# 2 step saving process

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Currently I have an application that has a 'Save' button. Upon touching this button the data gets updated in the database.
However, I want a 2 step process to be implemented. Upon 'Saving', all the data is to be saved in the db, but editable later.
However, if the data is 'Submitted' the data can only be viewed and not editable later.
In both cases I want the data to be reflected in the database.

How can I perform this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a field in your database which is going to hold the status EDITABLE true or false.
If you the data is submitted you change EDITABLE to true.
And every time you want to update the database you check if EDITABLE is true or false.

Answer (score 2):

In you datatable of SQL Lite you can have one more column call "Saved" with Boolean type, for the first time when the record is opened for edit mode you check the "Saved" column if it is true you show them non editable, if none or false you show the data editable.

Upon save you update the collumn value to true.

This way you can have functionality that for every record user can save data for first time and once saved they can not save it but only view it.